# HTTP Status 500 - Permission Denied

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

When I try to upload any file through website on folder which is present on server permission denied error occur . I have provided 0755 permissions to the folder. Locally this functionality works properly.

Comment: Care to show some code?

Comment: Also please add some more details. What exactly are you trying to do ? What server are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change owner of the folder. If you have created the folder using for example user `user` then based on 755 permission only him has access to write to the folder.

You have 2 options:

1. Change owner of the folder to the user running the webservice ( usually www:data ) using `chown`

   chown www:data upload_folder
2. **not recommended** : Change permission to `766` which allows everyone to have write permission.

Please provide more information in order to get a better answer from the community.